# What should be in my .gitignore for libGDX auto-generated default project?

Tags: git, libgdx, gitignore

So far I've got

```
bin/
gen/
war/
*.apk
/.settings/
*.class
```

But I know I'm missing loads because log files are getting into the repo. I keep seeing conflicting things about this, some people say keep the gen/ folder, and I found [a gitignore in the libgdx github](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/source/browse/.gitignore) with this(which I'm not sure if it's just for the actual library's git):

```
# android specific 
# */gen/*   ### we want these!


### eclipse files we DO want 
    # local.properties 
    # */.loadpath 
    # classpath 
    # settings
```

Anyways, this library seems like quite the big deal, so someone must have ***The*** .gitignore file for libGDX projects.

Comment: See http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44901/what-files-of-libgdx-can-i-ignore-on-git

Comment: I did see that actually, but I wasn't sure if the four things you mentioned were comprehensive, because I've seen regular old android gitignore files and they're a page long sometimes. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Generally ignore files which won't be used or make a garbage or have can be easily regenerated. Don't just blindly ignore everything. Short answer is: YOU DECIDE, there is no "should be"!

Ignore:

1. logs - because they show only moments of software running
2. dependency binaries (libraries) - it is up to you, I usually leave them, because it's not always obvious how and/or where to get them a year later.
3. your binaries - it's easy to recreate them based on source code and assets
4. assets - again, it's up to you. If you consider using some free hosting then putting 1GB of textures may be a problem, especcially if you update same textures
5. user settings files - especcially those which contain paths to folders on your hard disk. No one has your partitions except you.

What I wouldn't ignore:

- `gen` folder - sure it can be regenerated but updating
  that is rare and needs special commands to regenerate or opening
  project in Eclipse.
- Instead of ignoring `war` I would ignore only `classes` folder or just `*.class` as you did.
- `.classpath` file
- `.project` file
- `.settings` folder - just by looking into it I see that there are settings due to project like compiler version. That's rather important

Try to always think how to make less garbage and not stand in a way of next developer who just fetches the code for the first time. He/she doesn't want to download every library, regenerate everything, see logs and unneded for him settings.